# Lightning: Create new instance of aura:attribute of custom Apex type with default values

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

What is the way to create instance of Apex type inside `aura:attribute` or js controller (inside js onInit `<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}" />`) ?

For SObject it looks like:

```
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact"
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact',
           'LastName': 'Smith',
           'AccountId': '001i000002zxpz1' 
         }"/>
```

What is the right way to do it through component or js?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the model="" named attribute on your lightning component, or app. See below:

First line of my lightning application:

```
<aura:application model="ConfigurationModel" controller="ConfigurationController">
```

Here's my ConfigurationModel Apex class:

```
/**
* @author Charles Naccio
* @date 10/14/2015
*
* @group Configuration
* @group-content ../../ApexDocContent/Configuration.htm
*
* @description Configuration model class which is used by the Configuration lightning application. This class 
* provides the data needed for the lightning application's initial state.
*/
public with sharing class ConfigurationModel extends lightning_Response implements lightning_IResponse {

    /*******************************************************************************************************
    * @description List of supported gateways that can be configured.
    */
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String> supportedGateways {get;set;}

    /*******************************************************************************************************
    * @description Primary configured gateway. Although configuration is setup to support multiple gateways
    * we currently only support a single configured gateway.
    */
    @AuraEnabled
    public Gateway gateway {get;set;}

    /*******************************************************************************************************
    * @description Nested class to model gateway configuration in a lightning friendly way
    */
    private class Gateway {

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Gateway name
        */
        private String name {get;set;}

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Gateway login. This can either be an actual login to be used with password below, 
        * or an API key; whichever is needed for authentication.
        */
        private String login {get;set;}

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Gateway password if applicable
        */
        private String password {get;set;}

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Gateway application id; not used by all gateways
        */
        private String applicationId {get;set;}

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description If gateway is in test mode; defaults to false.
        */
        private Boolean testMode {get;set;}

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Configuration tab index controls where this configuration element is displayed in the UI
        */
        private Double tabIndex {get;set;}

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Create new instance of gateway configuration
        * @example
        * ConfigurationModel.Gateway gateway = new ConfigurationModel.Gateway(); 
        */
        private Gateway(Configuration configuration) {
            configuration_Merchant_Gateway gatewayConfiguration = configuration.merchant.gateways.primary;
            this.name = gatewayConfiguration.name;
            this.login = gatewayConfiguration.login;
            this.password = gatewayConfiguration.password;
            this.applicationId = gatewayConfiguration.applicationId;
            this.testMode = gatewayConfiguration.testMode;
            this.tabIndex = gatewayConfiguration.tabIndex;
        }

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Get configured gateway name
        * @return Configured gateway name
        * @example
        * String gatewayName = gateway.getName(); 
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;       
        }

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Get configured gateway Login
        * @return Configured gateway login
        * @example
        * String gatewayLogin = gateway.getLogin(); 
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public String getLogin() {
            return this.login;      
        }

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Get configured gateway password
        * @return Configured gateway password
        * @example
        * String gatewayPassword = gateway.getPassword(); 
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;       
        }

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Get configured gateway applicationId
        * @return Configured gateway applicationId
        * @example
        * String gatewayApplicationId = gateway.getApplicationId(); 
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public String getApplicationId() {
            return this.applicationId;      
        }

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Get configured gateway testMode
        * @return Configured gateway testMode
        * @example
        * Boolean gatewayTestMode = gateway.getTestMode(); 
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean getTestMode() {
            return this.testMode;       
        }

        /*******************************************************************************************************
        * @description Get configured gateway tabIndex
        * @return Configured gateway tabIndex
        * @example
        * Double gatewayTabIndex = gateway.getTabIndex(); 
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public Double getTabIndex() {
            return this.tabIndex;       
        }
    }

    /*******************************************************************************************************
    * @description Create new instance of Configuration Model
    * @example
    * ConfigurationModel configurationModel = new ConfigurationModel(); 
    */
    public ConfigurationModel() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            this.supportedGateways = configuration.merchant.gateways.supported;
            this.gateway = new Gateway(configuration);
        } catch(Exception e) {

            // Setup error
            this.error = new lightning_Response_Error(e);
        }
    }

    /*******************************************************************************************************
    * @description Return lightning response error
    * @example
    * lightning_Response_Error = new ConfigurationModel.getError();
    */
    @AuraEnabled
    public lightning_Response_Error getError() {
        return this.error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Natallia, I actually asked the [same question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54821/elegant-initialization-of-lightning-auraattribute) back in Winter '15, and I'm not sure whether the process is any different now in Spring '15. You can take a look at [the answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54821/elegant-initialization-of-lightning-auraattribute) to my question for specific instructions on how to initialize an attribute using an Apex method.

I'm definitely interested in learning from any others who have more experience or a better method of initializing attributes for Lightning components, because I don't like the fact that the component needs to make a round-trip call to Salesforce just to initialize some variables.

Comment: @ Marty C., Totally agree with your. Thanks a lot for the response.